# saving current date and time in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In my application i am using **In - App purchases** to provide a subscription of 1 year….now i need to save the time and date when the user buys the subscription and need to check when the subscription expires?? i have not used database before  is there any other way to store date and time in my application and retrieve it every time the application starts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store it in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate now] forKey:@"purchaseDate"];
```

Then retrieve it like such:

```
NSDate *purchaseDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"purchaseDate"];
```

And when you're done with it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"purchaseDate"];
```

Comment: I agree with Jacob, just make sure to delete the stored data when needed.

Comment: I do not agree with Jacob since this simplified solution do not cover loss of data, something that must be accounted for when real money is involved. A hard requirement from Apple.

Answer (score 3):

You should store the purchase of a subscription on a server, with backup in place, not only on the device.

You might have noticed that if you delete any iPhone app, and later re-install it, then the next download is free. There can be many reasons as to why the user might loose your app, a system update went bad, or whatever.

Apple specifically requires that the user do not loose what they have bought. If you have promised 1 year, then you must make sure they get 1 year no matter what happens to your app. Otherwise Apple can, and will, reject your app.

Storing the expiration date on a server also give the added benefit of protection against users fiddling with your data and granting themselves extended subscriptions.

Start by looking at the [In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/).

Comment: thanx i will also try to implement this method with my own.