# How to use a plist as persistent storage for iPhone app

Tags: iphone

how can we use plist as a database to store dates in iphone sdk

show me some link to study the plist

Comment: how many dates do you want to store? plists may or may not be the best match

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving current date and time in my iPhone application??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201623/saving-current-date-and-time-in-my-iphone-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-use-plist-in-iphone/

http://samsoff.es/posts/iphone-plist-tutorial

http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/05/iphone-tutorial-storing-and-retrieving.html

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.plist