# How to load and save the alpha of a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

How can I save and load the UIButton's alpha values in my iPhone app? I want to do this the easiest way possible. I have tried using various methods, but none have worked for me so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`CGFloat alpha = myButton.layer.opacity;`

You might need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`.

---

Edit (From this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201623/saving-current-date-and-time-in-my-iphone-application)):

Then, you can simply store it in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myButton.backgroundColor forKey:@"buttonColor"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];  // Thanks @Shah for reminding us about this!
```

Then retrieve it like such:

```
myButton.backgroundColor = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"buttonColor"];
```

And when you're done with it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"buttonColor"];
```

---

[NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: yes but how can I save and load these values when a user closes and opens the app again?

Comment: Oh, for that, you would want to check this out question [Saving Data in an iPhone App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201623/saving-current-date-and-time-in-my-iphone-application).  Updated answer to include the relative parts of that question.

Comment: done that but an error comes up with the retrieval code and says; Semantic Issue: Initializing 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') with an expression of incompatible type 'id' - and highlights the "btnAlpha" part in red.

Comment: Oh, I fixed the answer for that issue.  For the retrieval do this `NSNumber *btnAlpha = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"buttonAlpha"];` then `CGFloat floatAlpha = [btnAlpha floatValue];`

Comment: done that but doesn't change at all from before I added any of the code, the alpha still resets itself when the app is closed and relaunched... :(

Comment: Try saving the entire button color: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myButton.backgroundColor forKey:@"buttonColor"];` as the object in the NSUserDefaults.  Then to set it use `button.backgroundColor = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"buttonColor"];`

Comment: Sorry would you be able to provide a sample as I don't understand how I'd save the colour in NSUserDefaults as it's set to a number isn't it?

Comment: Check out the updated answer.  `UIColor` is the class and `backgroundColor` is the property of the `UIButton` object that you want to store/retrieve.  Setting the `UIColor` will also set the `alpha`.

Comment: I've done that now but still doesn't work! I think XCode is against me today :'(

Comment: Make sure you are calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myButton.backgroundColor forKey:@"buttonColor"];`

Comment: First, you dont need to call `synchronize` after each set, just after the last.  Also, put `NSLog(@"cross1.backgroundColor: %@", [cross1.backgroundColor description]);` before and after setting & getting the values, see if it changes or not.

Comment: will calling synchronize afer each set cause bugs or can I add it anyway? And I'll add the NSLog now to see what happens :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3329/discussion-between-chown-and-james-anderson)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
// Setting a value
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:VALUE forKey:KEY];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // This line is required to persist all changes make to the User Defraults

// Getting a value
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaylt] floatForKey:KEY];
```

Comment: what was the error you're getting? are you sure you used floatForKey instead of objectForKey?

Comment: yes definitely and I'm not getting any error, it just won't save/load the alpha values :(

Comment: could you please post some of the code? I just tried this example myself and it works like a charm.

Comment: In this code the value is not assigned to button's alpha. Use cross1.alpha = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"cross1alphasetting"]; You need to assign the loaded value to the button's alpha property.